Predicting if individual has a trait based on their previous locations (distribution of trait at locations is known)
I have been thinking about a problem and I was wondering if anyone has the right name/method/textbook of how this problem should be approached, or if they would be willing to help with finding a solution. My stats background is a bit shaky, so sorry if something is unclear/missing.
Say I have a large population of known size N where 10% have a trait T.
I have many locations where I have previously conducted a survey, where I measured this proportion of T in a random sample of individuals from the given location. Each location has a different distribution of the trait as it is known to vary from location to location.
Let say I have the following locations:



Location
Num with T
Num without T




L1
150
100


L2
190
210


...




Li
Ti
nTi



What is the probability of a certain individuals having the trait vs not having the trait given that they where observed at certain locations? e.g. a person was observed at the following locations: {L1, L3, L46} what is P(T|L1,L3,L46)? For each individual I have a complete list of which locations they have been to.
I'm wondering how I can incorporate information that certain distributions are farther from the population proportion and therefore more surprising e.g. if someone was observed at location L2 and multiple other sites similar to L2 it is much likelier they have the trait. Simply multiplying the probabilities doesn't seem to give the right solution e.g. if someone was observed at 10 highly irregular locations identical to L2 then simply multiplying the probabilities of having the trait would give a very small number: (190/400)^10 = 0.00058.
I would also be interested in how I could generalise this solution to either a multinomial distribution or continuous probability distributions in general.

Interesting problem. However, have you established that P(T) is indeed different among locations? I was thinking that you might first want to see if the data follows the binomial distribution (two outcomes - T and Not T, fixed number of trials (locations)). Now if the observed frequencies do not follow the expected frequencies (under the Binomial), then the only conclusion is that the third assumption of the Binomial (Prob stays constant from trial to trial) is violated. If you can first establish that, then you have at least eliminated the simple case scenario - and can then seek a solution f
